# Error while installing g++

Tags: installation, g++

I am getting this error:

```
sathiesh@sathiesh:~$ sudo apt-get install g++
[sudo] password for sathiesh: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do reinstall of gcc (together with g++) ?

As far as I know these both packages are always together ?

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like it points out `is another process using it?`, there may be another application holding `/var/lib/dpkg/lock`. Instead of finding and closing that program, better restart your computer and then issue the same command. I would recommend if you are using Ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

This will install all basic tools needed for building debian packages, which includes `g++` and `make`